# Where can I find Google Now source core in Android source tree

Tags: android, android-source, google-now

I just downloaded the Android source code from http://source.android.com, but I can't find **Google Now** source code under that tree.

Answer (score 9):

Nowhere, because Google Now (and the Google Search app which contains it) isn't part of the Android project; it's part of the Google Apps for Android, which aren't open-source.

Comment: I've been looking for this for a very long time-do you know how I can have continues voice recognition while the screen is off, just like Google now? Thanks so much!